# Use list of String as a parameter in elastic4s termsQuery

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I use as elastic4s library to communicate with ElasticSearch. I would like to make an equivalent of "SELECT * FROM WHERE MY_INDEX MY_FIELD IN (VALUE_1, VALUE_2, ....)"

I produced that query

```
val req = search in indexName -> {query indexType
   {bool
     must (
       termsQuery ("myField" transformed (myListOfValues))
     )
   }
}
```

The method termsQuery is defined as follows in elastis4s

```
def termsQuery (field: String, capital gains: AnyRef *): TermsQueryDefinition
```

How can I turn my myListOfValues list to a AnyRef *

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what the type of ListOfValue is, but assuming its a Scala collection type, then you can do '_ : *' eg

```
termsQuery ("myField", transformed (myListOfValues) : _*)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks monkjack it's now working :). The listOfValues is a String list.